# Hyperlink an Input Label in Semantic UI React

Tags: semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I have the following `<Form.Input>` that has a label I'd like users to be able to click, taking them to a new site in a new tab

```
<Form.Input 
    label='Icon (See Semantic Icons for options)' 
    name='icon' value={icon || ''} 
    onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

I don't see any documentation on how to achieve this - is it possible to embed a hyperlink within an attribute in Semantic UI React?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an element to the label prop, so you can do something like this

```
<Form.Input 
label={<div>Icon (<a href="www.semantic-options.com">See Semantic Icons for options</a>)</div>} 
name='icon' value={icon || ''} 
onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

Comment: Brilliant m8. Thank you!